# Polygon NFTs are not shown on metamask wallet

Tags: solidity, metamask

I've just deployed an ERC-1155 contract on polygon network. I've minted two tokens and these tokens are mine (even opensea undrestands it). But nothing is shown in metamask browser extension.

I've tried to import contract manually to metamask (Contract address, Symbol and set decimals to 0), but it keeps saying you have no tokens from this contract.

Any ideas how to show polygon ERC-1155 tokens on metamask?

Contract Address: 0x197D620b84351f22d1a227824af8DB0FDADEcF9c

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your *switched over to polygon network on your metamask wallet*? - I think it defaults to ETH network.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your reply. Yes, It's set to polygon (networkId: 137)